# How to round up a number if it's not an integer?

Tags: scala, double, ceil

I want to calculate a simple number, and if the number is not an integer I want to round it up.

For instance, if after a calculation I get `1.2`, I want to change it to `2`. If the number is `3.7`, I want to change it to `4` and so on.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `math.ceil` to round a `Double` up and `toInt` to convert the `Double` to an `Int`.

```
def roundUp(d: Double) = math.ceil(d).toInt

roundUp(1.2) // Int = 2
roundUp(3.7) // Int = 4
roundUp(5) // Int = 5
```

Comment: the thing is that im not sure if its double...im doing some calculation and the result can be either a double or an int

Comment: If it is an `Int` it will be converted to a `Double` for you automatically (see `roundUp(5)`).

Answer (score 0):

The [`ceil`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Double.html#ceil:Double) function is also directly accessible on the `Double`:

```
3.7.ceil.toInt // 4
```

Answer (score -1):

Having first imported math
`import scala.math._` (the final dot & underscore are crucial for what comes next)

you can simply write
`ceil(1.2)
floor(3.7)`

plus a bunch of other useful math functions like
`exp(1)
pow(2,2)
sqrt(pow(2,2)`